# Maven with Ubuntu 15.10, getting errors with: mvn clean install;

Tags: java, git, maven, ubuntu

I am using a vps hosted by TransIP that i bought yesterday. Every plugin works like it should except maven. Ive reinstalled it multiple times and it just seems to give errors the whole time.

What I did once I installed ubuntu 15.10 is:

1. sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
2. sudo apt-get install maven

Then I cloned my repository from github into the user folder named my name:

Path:/home/mart/[folder of the repo]

Once I was done I went to the folder and used: `mvn clean install`. It gave me this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Discordbot 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.782 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-03-13T14:51:14+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
```

My second thought was maybe I could run the project without needing to run `mvn clean install` and I ran `mvn exec:java`. Which then resulted in an error because it can't find the depencies.

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>martacus.mart.bot</groupId>
  <artifactId>Discordbot</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
      <repository>
        <id>bintray-thejavanerd-maven</id>
        <name>bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>com.github.austinv11</groupId>
         <artifactId>Discord4j</artifactId>
         <version>2.3.1</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dean.jraw</groupId>
        <artifactId>JRAW</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mashape.unirest</groupId>
        <artifactId>unirest-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>martacus.mart.bot.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

When I run 'mvn -version' I get:

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_66-internal, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.2.0-30-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

When I run 'java -version' I get:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_66-internal"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-internal-b17)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

When I searched around google people told me that it had something to do with my proxy settings. But I am using a vps and the company couldnt give me the proxy settings.. Maybe if there is a way to find out what they are it might solve the problem, but I haven't found a way to get those yet.

If you'd like to see my repo on github for more information about the project: https://github.com/Martacus/DiscordBot

Everything works on my normal computer, but ofcourse the settings for everything is different and I use windows 8. I do hope people can help me and if you would need more information make sure to let me know!

Comment: Check if you can access to external resources by https protocol. Run `wget https://www.google.com` You should obtain an `index.html` file.

Comment: I can do that Ortomala

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's maybe related to a problem of ca-certificates, try to run this command:

```
update-ca-certificates -f
```

According to the man page:

```
update-ca-certificates is a program that updates the directory /etc/ssl/certs to 
hold SSL certificates and generatescertificates.crt, a concatenated single-file 
list of certificates.
```

Comment: Okay so i got this right now:
'    <proxy>
      <id>optional</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username>mart</username>
      <password>Pass</password>
      <host>proxy.yoyodyne.net</host>
      <port>18023</port>
      <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
' 
But it doesnt seem to help. If i change the host it gets stuck, but if it is this it goes with it but I get the exact same error. @Ortomala